# How to make Julia multiple dispatch hierarchy work on array contents

Tags: types, julia

I want to have a function that takes in an array of numbers and does some operation on them. To do this, I created the function

```
function squarearray(numinarray::Vector{Number})
  numinarray[1]^2
end
```

But when I tried calling it with

```
print(squarearray(Vector([1.0])))
```

it caused an error:

> ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching squarearray(::Vector{Float64})
> Closest candidates are:
> squarearray(::Vector{Number}) at ~/Programming/ai/structlearn.jl:7
> squarearray(::AbstractVector{Number}) at ~/Programming/ai/structlearn.jl:7

`Float64` is a subtype of `Number`, so why won't this work? I know I could specify in the function that it takes in in array of floats, but I also want the function to work on ints.

Thanks!

-Diego

Comment: You want `squarearray(numinarray::Vector{<:Number})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Number" Type is Abstract. This means no data can be directly of type Number. However, as you pointed out, Number has concrete subtypes, such as Float64. If you change

```
numinarray::Vector{<:Number} #limits to only subtypes of Number
```

or

```
numinarray::Vector{Float64} #limits to Float64 type
```

or

```
numinarray::Vector #Does not limit inputs
```

You should avoid the problem.